# Left-align axis text for facet_grid plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to left-align the left axis text, but nothing changes. Any suggestions? I also tried   `axis.text.y.left` .

```
  ggplot(ann.raw.reads,aes(primaryTumorLocation, y=value)) +
  geom_blank() +
  theme_bw(base_size=6) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(vars(primaryTumorLocation), scales="free")


structure(list(primaryTumorLocation = structure(1:38, levels = c("Nervous system\tNervous system", 
"Eye\tEye", "Head and neck\tHead and neck", "Thyroid gland\tThyroid gland", 
"Trachea\tTrachea", "Lymphoid tissue\tLymphoid tissue", "Thymus\tThymus", 
"Bronchus\tBronchus", "Lung\tLung", "Mesothelium\tMesothelium", 
"Breast\tBreast", "Gastrointestinal cancer\tHepatobiliary system", 
"Gastrointestinal cancer\tLiver", "Gastrointestinal cancer\tBile duct", 
"Gastrointestinal cancer\tGallbladder", "Gastrointestinal cancer\tGastroesophageal", 
"Gastrointestinal cancer\tEsophagus", "Gastrointestinal cancer\tGastrointestinal tract", 
"Gastrointestinal cancer\tAnus", "Gastrointestinal cancer\tColorectum", 
"Gastrointestinal cancer\tSmall intestine", "Gastrointestinal cancer\tAppendix", 
"Gastrointestinal cancer\tStomach", "Gastrointestinal cancer\tPancreas", 
"Bone marrow\tBone marrow", "Adrenal gland\tAdrenal gland", "Kidney\tKidney", 
"Prostate\tProstate", "Reproductive organs\tOvary", "Reproductive organs\tFallopian tube", 
"Reproductive organs\tUrothelial tract", "Reproductive organs\tUterus", 
"Reproductive organs\tVagina", "Reproductive organs\tVulva", 
"Reproductive organs\tTestis", "Reproductive organs\tPenis", 
"Skin\tSkin", "Bone/Soft tissue\tBone/Soft tissue"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), ID = c("Nervous system", "Eye", "Head and neck", 
    "Thyroid gland", "Trachea", "Lymphoid tissue", "Thymus", 
    "Bronchus", "Lung", "Mesothelium", "Breast", "Hepatobiliary system", 
    "Liver", "Bile duct", "Gallbladder", "Gastroesophageal", 
    "Esophagus", "Gastrointestinal tract", "Anus", "Colorectum", 
    "Small intestine", "Appendix", "Stomach", "Pancreas", "Bone marrow", 
    "Adrenal gland", "Kidney", "Prostate", "Ovary", "Fallopian tube", 
    "Urothelial tract", "Uterus", "Vagina", "Vulva", "Testis", 
    "Penis", "Skin", "Bone/Soft tissue")), row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Seems to be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080119/alignment-of-y-axis-labels-in-faced-grid-and-ggplot